# DecimalFormat in Java program, I get an error that says cannot find symbol twoDigitPattern

Tags: java, compiler-errors, decimalformat

The code below, was tested and all runs great, until I added the DecimalFormat. Now it errors and says it can not find the symbol "twoDigitPattern".  I tried to use + DecimalFormat(average)) and it also errors.

```
class IntegerInputWithCkAndAverage
{

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      final int SENTINEL = 0;
      int numEntered = 0;
      int accumulator = 0;
      int counter = 0;
      double average = 0;

      Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.print( "Enter a integer, or 0 to end > " );
      while( !scan.hasNextInt() ) {
         String garbage = scan.nextLine();
         System.out.
                 print( "Invalid input. Please enter an integer, or 0 to end" );
      }
      numEntered = Integer.parseInt( scan.nextLine() );
      while( numEntered != SENTINEL ) {
         accumulator = accumulator + numEntered;
         counter++;
         System.out.print( "Enter another integer, or 0 to end> " );
         while( !scan.hasNextInt() ) {
            String garbage = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print( 
                    "Invalid input. Please enter an integer or 0 to end" );
         }
         numEntered = Integer.parseInt( scan.nextLine() );
      }
      average = (double) accumulator / counter;
      DecimalFormat twoDigitPattern = new DecimalFormat( "#0.00" );
      System.out.println( 
              "the total of the " + counter + "numbers entered is " +
               accumulator + " and the average is " + twoDigitPattern( average ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: did it work with my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
twoDigitPattern(average)
```

to

```
twoDigitPattern.format(average)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a weird error message for omitting a method dereference.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: That is perfect.  I looked all over online and in my textbook... seems so easy, but it literally was no where to be found.